# android - why doesn't create "Binding" for a layout

Tags: java, android

i created activity to name of "RegisterActivity.java" but, why "ActivityRegisterBinding" has not been creating ? intersting , i before create "RegisterActivity.java" ,i was creating activity "LoginActivity.java" and it has "ActivityLoginBinding".
can explain me, please ?

this is layout of RegisterActivity.java :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.RegisterActivity">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and login layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="MyViewModel"
            type="com.example.questionandanswer.viewModel.MyViewModel" />
    </data>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isScrollContainer="true">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".View.MainActivity">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtEmailAddress"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="E-Mail Address"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:text="@={MyViewModel.EmailAddress}"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtPassword"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:text="@={MyViewModel.Password}"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtEmailAddress" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:text="Click to Login"
                android:onClick="@{(v) -> MyViewModel.onClick(v)}"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPassword" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
                android:layout_width="416dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</layout>
```

thanks

Comment: Can you share your layouts?

Comment: yes ,layout was adding.

Comment: How is the login layout?

Comment: sorry ,login layout was adding.

Comment: Put the register layout in the ‘layout’ tag then your problem will be resolved

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`activity_register.xml` needs to be wrapped in a `<layout>` tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".view.RegisterActivity">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

It is the `<layout>` that tells DataBinding plugin to generate the binding code.